# PHP: Add multiple entries to array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a string and a value.
I am exploding the string which returns a few results to a list.
I want to add each of those items from the list to an array, with the same value assigned to each string.
Here is what I have so far:

```
$count = 3;
$amount = 2500;
$value = ceil ($amount / $count);
$string = "String1, String2, String3, ";
$strings = explode(", ", $string);
```

I want to run a foreach that puts $strings and $value into an array together.
Any pointers?

Comment: What do you mean by "together"?  `array(String1, String2, String3, 834)` or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
$combo = array_fill_keys( $strings , $value );
// var_dump( $combo ); // to check you got it right.
```

This takes the values in your `$strings` array and uses them as the keys for the new `$combo` array, setting the same value for each key.